# Check if a port is installed on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

How can one check if a port is already installed on FreeBSD?

This is to be used in a shell script for provisioning. i.e. if port is already installed skip install, else call `make` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under FreeBSD 10+, you can use "pkg". The good reference is: https://wiki.freebsd.org/PkgPrimer

If your port is installed, it will result in:

```
# pkg info apache-jmeter
apache-jmeter-3.0.r2
Name           : apache-jmeter
Version        : 3.0.r2
Installed on   : Thu May  5 18:58:45 2016 MSK
Origin         : www/jmeter
Architecture   : freebsd:10:x86:64
...
```

Otherwise:

```
# pkg info jmeter
pkg: No package(s) matching jmeter
```

Comment: Cheers Michael. Just incase anyone finds this useful.. `pkg info` gives the correct exit codes when ports are or are not found. This means the returned string doesn't need to be parsed to check if it is installed and instead can be simply written as a boolean: `if ! pkg info mysql56-server ; then # install mysql logic here... fi`

Comment: Just be sure to remember the difference between "packages" and "ports" on FreeBSD 9and other *BSDs). You install a port on your local system through a series of make scripts which build the programme from source and, bundle it up as a package and install that on your system. You should never use "pkg delete"/"pkg remove" on software that you have installed via the ports, but rather "make deinstall" from inside the ports tree. Doing "pkg install" downloads a precompiled package to your system and installs it.  Doing "pkg info <packagename>" will *not* tell you if it was installed from ports.

Answer (score 0):

> You should never use "pkg delete"/"pkg remove" on software that you have installed via 
>   the ports, but rather "make deinstall" from inside the ports tree. Doing "pkg install" 
>   downloads a precompiled package to your system and installs it.
>   Doing "pkg info " will *not tell you if it was installed from ports.

I'm afraid the quoted statements are incorrect.

A 'port' is simply a 'package' that hasn't been compiled and installed yet.
Installed ports are in fact packages and can be treated like any other package regardless if it was downloaded pre-compiled and installed via pkg(8) or compiled locally from the ports tree and then installed. The terms 'port' and 'package' are synonymous once the software is 'installed'.

`pkg delete/remove <portname>` can and should be used and may be preferable as it will prompt to also uninstall no longer needed dependencies.
`make deinstall` in a specific port's directory will only uninstall that port and nothing else.

`pkg info` `pkg info <portname>` is the correct answer.

Comment: Where is this quote from?